# how to get access to the methods of the target entity of unidirectional ManyToOne association

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, symfony4

I am stuck here I execute the query:

```
public function findByFile_Ref_Id($query)
{
    $query = $query['ids'];

    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('h');
    $result = $q
        ->join('h.file_ref_id', 'k')
        ->add('where', $q->expr()->in('k.product_code', $query))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

and I get something like this:

> array:5 [▼
>
> 0 => HikashopFile {#417 ▼
>
> -file_id: 2207
>
> -file_path: "1TAHBIO.jpg"
>
> -file_ref_id: KstoreHikashopProduct {#363 ▼
>
> +**isInitialized**: true
>
> -product_id: 6
>
> -product_name: "Tahina bio"
>
> -product_description: "
>
> La Tahina è una crema di sesamo biologica. Rafforza il sistema immunitario grazie alla presenza di sali e
> vitamine, contiene un elevato contenuto di calcio, ▶"
>
> -product_quantity: 3
>
> -product_code: "1TAHBIO" …2 } }

I want to access the methods of that target entity to do some tasks.

but when I try I get :

> Return value of App\Entity\HikashopFile::getFileRefId() must be of the
> type int or null, object returned

or

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getProductName" of class
> "App\Entity\HikashopFile".

there is clearly something wrong in my code.

help would be appreciated!

Comment: doctrine orm (which is used here) is working with *objects* and what I have seen so far implies you're using ids. doctrine hydration doesn't use the setters either, so your `file_ref_id` property holds a `HikashopProduct` object instead of an id. however, your `getFileRefId` function is supposed to return an int or null (according to error message, which probably stems from the function *signature*). there are a lot of code smells probably...

Answer (score 0):

check if you have a methode named "getProductName"  in your "HikashopFile" entity if no **create it** if yes **delete it and generate getters and setters**

Answer (score 0):

Your method **getFileRefId()** is surely waiting to return an int or a null at the typing level like :

```
public function getFileRefId(): ?int 
{
     return $this->fileRefId;
}
```

Try to remove typing maybe it will works.

I think you have a problems with your relations between your entities because you want to get the Id of other table but with doctrine, it will give you the object corresponding to the identifier

Check doctrine doc : [Doc doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html)